# Angularjs radio button value used in api link

Tags: angularjs, fetch

I want to use the value of a radio button and implement that into an api link but its not linking for some reason.

**heres my code**

**JS**

```
myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.doIt = function() {
            $scope.targetURL = ('https://api.api/' + $scope.formData + '/us/profile');

            $http.get($scope.targetURL)
                .success(function(results) {
                    $scope.data = results.data;
                });
        };
    }
]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="background">
   <div class="transbox">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label><input type="radio" name='radio' value="pc" ng-model="formData"><img src="../img/battlenet.png"></label>
            <label><input type="radio" name='radio' value="psn" ng-model="formData"><img src="../img/playstation.png"></label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-5">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Gamertag">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="doIt()"> Submit </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lfrecia/Lvc0u55v/11417/):

```
myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.doIt = function() {
            $scope.targetURL = ('https://api.api/' + $scope.formData + '/us/profile');

            $http.get($scope.targetURL)
                .success(function(results) {
                    $scope.data = results.data;
                });
        };
    }
    ]);
```

And your HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="background">
         <div class="transbox">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-4">
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <label><input type="radio" name='radio' value="pc" ng-model="formData"><img src="../img/battlenet.png"></label>
                  <label><input type="radio" name='radio' value="psn" ng-model="formData"><img src="../img/playstation.png"></label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-5">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-9">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Gamertag">
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="doIt()"> Submit </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I think you are not calling the controller, at least in your example it is not. If you check the network tab in the chrome console for the requests, you will see the correct data is sent:

```
https://api.api/pc/us/profile
https://api.api/psn/us/profile
```

Comment: change your scope variable from object $scope.formData = {}; to $scope.formData = null;